# Trying to style with columns and 4 divs per column but not styling properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

Im trying to get these articles to be displayed vertically (one on top of the other) and then 4 divs per column of the main section. I can't them to eb the same size or for all of them to display the articles stacked on top of each other. Some keep going side by side. I can't figure out what to do.

```
    <div class="indexNPrt2Mid" >
      <div class ="row flex-wrap">
        <div class = "col-lg-6 flex-first">
      <div class="indexNPrt2MidSlider">
        <div class="ylwTpBx wlwTpBx clearfix pointer">
          <h3 (click)="navigateToArticles(19)">Daily Fantasy Basketball<span><img
            src="../../../../assets/images/blkArow.png"></span></h3>
          <p><img src="../../../../assets/images/basketball.png" alt="" class="img-responsive"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme midSlider midSlider1">
          <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" (click)="switchToSingle(article)" class="item pointer"
               *ngFor="let article of basketballArticles">
            <img style="width: 100%;height:auto;"
                 [attr.src]="findMedia(article.featured_media) ? findMedia(article.featured_media) : '../../../../assets/images/Basketball.jpg'"
                 alt="" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="nltstNwsInfoTpWrp">
              <h4><a>{{article.title.rendered}}</a></h4>
              <!-- <p>{{article.extract?.slice(0,15)}}...</p>-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        <div class="indexNPrt2MidSlider">
        <div class="ylwTpBx wlwTpBx clearfix pointer">
          <h3 (click)="navigateToArticles(17)">Daily Fantasy Baseball<span><img
            src="../../../../assets/images/blkArow.png"></span></h3>
          <p><img src="../../../../assets/images/baseball.png" alt="" class="img-responsive"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme midSlider midSlider2">
          <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" (click)="switchToSingle(article)" class="item pointer"
               *ngFor="let article of baseballArticles">
            <img style="width: 100%;height:auto;"
                 [attr.src]="findMedia(article.featured_media) ? findMedia(article.featured_media) : '../../../../assets/images/base-ball.jpg'"
                 alt="" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="nltstNwsInfoTpWrp">
              <h4><a>{{article.title.rendered}}</a></h4>
              <!-- <p>{{article.extract?.slice(0,15)}}...</p>-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="indexNPrt2MidSlider">
        <div class="ylwTpBx wlwTpBx clearfix pointer">
          <h3 (click)="navigateToArticles(16)">Daily Fantasy Football<span><img
            src="../../../../assets/images/blkArow.png"></span></h3>
          <p><img src="../../../../assets/images/football.png" alt="" class="img-responsive"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme midSlider midSlider3">
          <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" (click)="switchToSingle(article)" class="item pointer"
               *ngFor="let article of footballArticles">
            <img style="width: 100%;height:auto;"
                 [attr.src]="findMedia(article.featured_media) ? findMedia(article.featured_media) : '../../../../assets/images/football.jpg'"
                 alt="" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="nltstNwsInfoTpWrp">
              <h4><a>{{article.title.rendered}}</a></h4>
              <!-- <p>{{article.extract?.slice(0,15)}}...</p>-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="indexNPrt2MidSlider">
        <div class="ylwTpBx wlwTpBx clearfix pointer">
          <h3 (click)="navigateToArticles(18)">Daily Fantasy Hockey<span><img
            src="../../../../assets/images/blkArow.png"></span></h3>
          <p><img src="../../../../assets/images/football.png" alt='' class="img-responsive"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme midSlider midSlider4">
          <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" (click)="switchToSingle(article)" class="item pointer"
               *ngFor="let article of hockeyArticles">
            <img style="width: 100%;height:auto;"
                 [attr.src]="findMedia(article.featured_media) ? findMedia(article.featured_media) : '../../../../assets/images/Basketball.jpg'"
                 alt="" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="nltstNwsInfoTpWrp">
              <h4><a>{{article.title.rendered}}</a></h4>
              <!-- <p>{{article.extract?.slice(0,15)}}...</p>-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
        <div class = "col-lg-6 flex-last">
      <div class="indexNPrt2MidSlider">
        <div class="ylwTpBx wlwTpBx clearfix pointer">
          <h3 (click)="navigateToArticles(18)">Daily Fantasy Soccer<span><img
            src="../../../../assets/images/blkArow.png"></span></h3>
          <p><img src="../../../../assets/images/football.png" alt='' class="img-responsive"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme midSlider midSlider4">
          <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" (click)="switchToSingle(article)" class="item pointer"
               *ngFor="let article of soccerArticles">
            <img style="width: 100%;height:auto;"
                 [attr.src]="findMedia(article.featured_media) ? findMedia(article.featured_media) : '../../../../assets/images/Basketball.jpg'"
                 alt="" class="img-responsive">

            <div class="nltstNwsInfoTpWrp">
              <h4><a>{{article.title.rendered}}</a></h4>
              <!-- <p>{{article.extract?.slice(0,15)}}...</p>-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="indexNPrt2MidSlider">
        <div class="ylwTpBx wlwTpBx clearfix pointer">
          <h3 (click)="navigateToArticles(18)">Daily Fantasy Golf<span><img
            src="../../../../assets/images/blkArow.png"></span></h3>
          <p><img src="../../../../assets/images/football.png" alt='' class="img-responsive"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme midSlider midSlider4">
          <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" (click)="switchToSingle(article)" class="item pointer"
               *ngFor="let article of golfArticles">
            <img style="width: 100%;height:auto;"
                 [attr.src]="findMedia(article.featured_media) ? findMedia(article.featured_media) : '../../../../assets/images/Basketball.jpg'"
                 alt="" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="nltstNwsInfoTpWrp">
              <h4><a>{{article.title.rendered}}</a></h4>
              <!-- <p>{{article.extract?.slice(0,15)}}...</p>-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="indexNPrt2MidSlider">
        <div class="ylwTpBx wlwTpBx clearfix pointer">
          <h3 (click)="navigateToArticles(18)">Daily Fantasy MMA<span><img
            src="../../../../assets/images/blkArow.png"></span></h3>
          <p><img src="../../../../assets/images/football.png" alt='' class="img-responsive"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme midSlider midSlider4">
          <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" (click)="switchToSingle(article)" class="item pointer"
               *ngFor="let article of mmaArticles">
            <img style="width: 100%;height:auto;"
                 [attr.src]="findMedia(article.featured_media) ? findMedia(article.featured_media) : '../../../../assets/images/Basketball.jpg'"
                 alt="" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="nltstNwsInfoTpWrp">
              <h4><a>{{article.title.rendered}}</a></h4>
              <!-- <p>{{article.extract?.slice(0,15)}}...</p>-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="indexNPrt2MidSlider">
        <div class="ylwTpBx wlwTpBx clearfix pointer">
          <h3 (click)="navigateToArticles(18)">Daily Fantasy Racing<span><img
            src="../../../../assets/images/blkArow.png"></span></h3>
          <p><img src="../../../../assets/images/football.png" alt='' class="img-responsive"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme midSlider midSlider4">
          <div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" (click)="switchToSingle(article)" class="item pointer"
               *ngFor="let article of nascarArticles">
            <img style="width: 100%;height:auto;"
                 [attr.src]="findMedia(article.featured_media) ? findMedia(article.featured_media) : '../../../../assets/images/Basketball.jpg'"
                 alt="" class="img-responsive">
            <div class="nltstNwsInfoTpWrp">
              <h4><a>{{article.title.rendered}}</a></h4>
              <!-- <p>{{article.extract?.slice(0,15)}}...</p>-->
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>

     <div class="indexNPrt2Rght">
       <div class="ylwTpBx clearfix">
         <h3 routerLink="/news">Social Feeds <span><img src="../../../../assets/images/blkArow.png"></span></h3>
         <p><img src="../../../../assets/images/rght_icn3.png" alt="" class="img-responsive"></p>
       </div>

       <!-- Nav tabs -->
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#nTwtr" aria-controls="nTwtr" role="tab"
                                                  data-toggle="tab"><img
          src="../../../../assets/images/twitter_icn.png" alt=""></a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#nFb" aria-controls="nFb" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><img
          src="../../../../assets/images/facebook_icn.png" alt=""></a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#nInsta" aria-controls="nInsta" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><img
          src="../../../../assets/images/insta_icn.png" alt=""></a></li>
      </ul>


      <!-- Tab panes -->
     <div class="tab-content" style="height:1700px;overlflow:scroll;">

       <div class="nSocialTbWrap">
            <div class="nSocialTbBx" *ngFor="let tweet of twitterFeeds">
              <img
                [attr.src]="tweet?.user?.profile_banner_url ? tweet?.user?.profile_banner_url : '../../../../assets/images/twitter-befault.jpg'"
                alt="" class="img-responsive social-feed-img"/>
              <div class="nSocialTbBxInfo">
                <div class="nSocialTbBxInfoTp clearfix">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="icnWrapperS">{{tweet?.user.name}}</span><i><img
                    src="../../../../assets/images/twitter_icn.png"></i></a>
                  <div class="nltstNwsInfoTme">
                    <span class="icnWrapperS"><img src="../../../../assets/images/nclck_icn.png" alt=""
                                                   class="img-responsive"></span>
                    <i>{{tweet.created_at |date:'dd MMM, yyyy h:m a'}}</i>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p>{{tweet?.text?.slice(0,150)}}...</p>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nRdMor">Read More <span><img
                  src="../../../../assets/images/blkArow.png"></span></a>
              </div>
            </div>
       </div>

        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="nFb">
          <div class="nSocialTbWrap">
            <div class="nSocialTbBx" *ngFor="let tweet of facebookFeeds">
              <img
                [attr.src]="tweet?.attachments?.data[0]?.media?.image?.src ? tweet?.attachments?.data[0]?.media?.image?.src :'../../../../assets/images/f-default.jpg'"
                alt="" class="img-responsive social-feed-img"/>
              <div class="nSocialTbBxInfo">
                <div class="nSocialTbBxInfoTp clearfix">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="icnWrapperS">{{tweet?.message}}</span><i><img
                    src="../../../../assets/images/facebook_icn.png"></i></a>
                  <div class="nltstNwsInfoTme">
                    <span class="icnWrapperS"><img src="../../../../assets/images/nclck_icn.png" alt=""
                                                   class="img-responsive"></span>
                    <i>{{tweet.created_at |date:'dd MMM, yyyy h:m a'}}</i>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p>{{tweet?.text?.slice(0,150)}}...</p>
                <a href="{{tweet?.attachments?.data[0]?.url}}" target="_blank" class="nRdMor">Read More <span><img
                  src="../../../../assets/images/blkArow.png"></span></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="nInsta">
          <div class="nSocialTbWrap">
            <div class="nSocialTbBx" *ngFor="let tweet of instagramFeeds">
              <img
                [attr.src]="tweet?.images?.thumbnail?.url ? tweet?.images?.thumbnail?.url :'../../../../assets/images/f-default.jpg'"
                alt="" class="img-responsive social-feed-img"/>
              <div class="nSocialTbBxInfo">
                <div class="nSocialTbBxInfoTp clearfix">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="icnWrapperS">{{tweet?.user.full_name}}</span><i><img
                    src="../../../../assets/images/insta_icn.png"></i></a>
                  <!--<div class="nltstNwsInfoTme">
                    <span class="icnWrapperS"><img src="../../../../assets/images/nclck_icn.png" alt=""
                                                   class="img-responsive"></span>
                    <i>{{tweet.created_time |date:'dd MMM, yyyy h:m a'}}</i>
                  </div>-->
                </div>
                <p>{{tweet?.caption?.slice(0,150)}}...</p>
                <a href="{{tweet?.link}}" class="nRdMor" target="_blank">Read More <span><img
                  src="../../../../assets/images/blkArow.png"></span></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my code. The exterior div (indexNPrt2Mid) is meant to be displayed in the center of the page with two columns that have the other 8 divs included in them, with even heights, widths and three articles displayed in a stacked configuration. I dont know where my issue is coming from .

here is the CSS:

```
.news-notes {
/* text-align: justify; */
}
.body {
  width: 100%;
}
.indexNPrt2MidSlider{
 height: 25%;

}

.indexNPrt2Mid {
 columns: 2;

}


.social-feed-img {
height: auto;
 width: 100%;
}

.news-item {
 border-top: 1px solid #eee;
}

.news-item:first-child {
border-top: none;
}

.pointer {
 cursor: pointer;
}


.TopText {
margin-top: -5em;
font-size: 2em;
color: white;
}
.TopText div {
font-size: 3em;
}
.TopText h1 {
font-size: 2em;
color: white;
 }

#myBtn {
 display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Fixed/sticky position */
bottom: 20px; /* Place the button at the bottom of the page */
right: 30px; /* Place the button 30px from the right */
z-index: 99; /* Make sure it does not overlap */
border: none; /* Remove borders */
outline: none; /* Remove outline */
background-color: red; /* Set a background color */
color: white; /* Text color */
cursor: pointer; /* Add a mouse pointer on hover */
padding: 15px; /* Some padding */
border-radius: 10px; /* Rounded corners */
font-size: 18px; /* Increase font size */
}

#myBtn:hover {
background-color: #555; /* Add a dark-grey background on hover */
}
.backToTopButton.visible {
  opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
}

.backToTopButton .backToTopArrow {
transform: rotate(-135deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
display: block;
}
.backToTopButton i {
position: absolute;
top: 1.25rem;
right: 1.0625rem;
 padding: .5rem;
border: solid #fff;
border-width: 0 .15rem .15rem 0;
}
i {
 display: inline-block;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 float: inherit;
text-align: inherit;
}
*, :after, :before {
box-sizing: content-box;
}

.tab-content::-webkit-scrollbar{
 overflow-scrolling: auto;
 overflow: auto;
 height: auto;
 padding: .5rem;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
-ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

Comment: based on the layout, I would recommend using bootstrap which will do the stacking for you, also you can divide a column into 4 divs equally. Its much easier

Comment: Please show your css or it is impossible to work out what your problem is.

Comment: Added the css @leoFarmer

Comment: @AmirHosseinRd So I used bootstrap but I can't get the second column to show up beside the first one. Am I doing something wrong? I will add it into the question above

Answer (score 0):

So here is how I could do the layout. if you resize you see it will stack on top of eachother

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 " style="border: 1px solid red; width:100%; height: 50vh;">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="border:2px solid black;height:50vh;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="border:2px solid green;height:50vh;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="border:2px solid blue;height:50vh;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="border:2px solid yellow;height:50vh">
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
   <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 " style="border: 1px solid green; width:100%; height: 50vh;">

   </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 " style="border: 1px solid blue; width:100%; height: 50vh;">
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style="border: 1px solid orange; width:100%; height: 50vh;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="border:2px solid black;height:50vh;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="border:2px solid green;height:50vh;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="border:2px solid blue;height:50vh;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="border:2px solid yellow;height:50vh">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```